# How can there be multiple FROM addresses in one contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, etherscan, java

As I understood, there cannot be several senders for eth. How to make such a contract?
For example, here is a transaction with several addresses, this is a swap, but it's still not clear how:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcd807fdae908e71e6448308b2936eb576210cc6dea3881b94ac66601901bceb6

maybe by this example?
[How to combine multiple inputs addresses using contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33776/how-to-combine-multiple-inputs-addresses-using-contract)
how many transactions and commissions will there be?

Comment: there can't be multiple senders of one transaction. There is always one sender. This transaction also has 1 sender

Comment: since this transaction transfers tokens, you can have infinite amount of transfers of such kind